# Divi : Hide Button when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm a novice in jQuery coding, and I need help with my code. 
I have a button that allows me to reveal a hidden section on my website, but at the moment the button remains even though I want him to disappear.
My website is built with Wordpress and Divi.

With the following code, you will have my latest attempt with the hide/show value in CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
.rv_button.closed:after {content:"";}
.rv_button.opened:after {content:"";}
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#reveal').hide();

  jQuery('.rv_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#reveal").slideToggle();
    jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
  });
});

</script>
```

If you want to see what it looks like, you can see the example here: https://divinotes.com/reveal-a-hidden-divi-section-row-or-module-on-button-click/

Comment: Can you include your html / markup too, please?

Comment: Also, let us know if there are any errors in your browser's console.

Comment: Nothing in that code or CSS would hide the button. What aren't you showing us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `$(this).hide()` in your click function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#reveal').hide();

        jQuery('.rv_button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#reveal").slideToggle();
            jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');

            // Hide button
            $(this).hide()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're toggling classes named `opened` and `closed`, while your CSS shows that `hide` and `show` are the ones affecting element's presence in the final render of the page. Also there's probably no need for most classes. You can just add the `hide` one.

Chance your last non-trivial line to

```
jQuery('.rv_button').addClass('hide');
```

If you already have `show` class applied to the button, then your original idea makes sense. You just need to change the classes to match the ones you defined in styles.

```
jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('show hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your involvment in my question. I managed to use the solution of @vmf91 which works like a charm. Thanks again guys and have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the button after clicking over it? If so, you just need to insert the following line inside the button event:

```
jQuery(this).hide();
```

The complete click event:

```
jQuery('.rv_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery("#reveal").slideToggle();

    //You don't need this if you want to hide the button
    //jQuery('.rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```